Minio and application cache
I would like to understand how Minio scales for the case described below, and how to scale it.
There is a service with 12 nodes running in Kubernetes. The service runs in a private cloud. This service caches some data in the process memory. The total size of the caches is about 2 GB. There are about 30 different types of caches in the service memory. When the service starts, it accesses the database, fills the caches, and only then informs Kubernetes that it is ready to process user requests. Caches are updated on schedule, once every few hours.
There is a problem with this scheme, it lies in the long deployment of hotfixes. Now the rollout of changes is carried out by several nodes, and each such group starts in 150 seconds, due to the filling of the cache from the database. I am thinking about how to make it faster.
There are two main options.
The first option is to write the contents of the caches to files in a local folder after each update, using PVC. At startup, accordingly, fill the caches from the files. If they are not found there, then read from the DB. For the data that is cached, some lag from the DB is quite acceptable.
The second option is to write their contents not to a folder on a local disk, but to S3 storage, Minio. Read at startup, respectively, from there. If for some cache of data there is no data, read from the DB.
The first option is clear, it is completely horizontally scalable. But it is more difficult to configure and support.
The second option looks more interesting. But, perhaps, it will read files for a longer time and scale worse.
To what extent is Minio suitable for the described solution, are there any obvious problems in this solution?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
